# Fgets function in for loop overwrittes old input

Tags: c

I'am trying to write Names into a char array. I'am using fgets for this. My problem is that my code overwrittes the old input each time their is a new one.

I'am using the compare for NULL because I want to end the input sequency with pressing CTRL+D.

```
char input[MAX];

for(;;) {
    printf("Input:\n");
    if (fgets(input, MAX, file) == NULL){
        printf("EOF\n");
        break;
    }
}
printf("%s", input);
```

Comment: `char input[MAX];` can only hold one string, `MAX-1` characters in length.  To contain a new string for each iteration of the loop it would need to be a 2D array, or similar, with the first index equal to the number of strings you need to store:  `char input[num_strings][MAX];`.  Also, your code snippet for a question like this should be a complete [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited for portability.  (replaced VLA with fixed length array.)

*"I don't understand why I need a 2 Dimension Array"*

```
char input[MAX];
```

creates space for a *single* char array with space for `MAX-1` characters, leaving one byte for the terminating null character, `\0`.

"Anna", "Peter" and "Leonie" are each null terminated char arrays, each defining a C string.  If they are to be stored in an array, the array needs to be created with space for each of them, and each space needs its own starting location provided by the value of the first index in the declaration:

```
   char input[NUM_STRINGS][MAX];
```

The second index provides the space.  Now each string has its own space, as shown here:

```
input[0]//each of following can contain up to MAX-1 characters
input[1]
input[3]
...
input[num_strings]
```

This example implements what my comments under your question were trying to explain...

```
#define MAX 100
#define NUM_STRINGS 10

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char input[NUM_STRINGS][MAX] = {0};//zeroed to initialize    
    for(int i = 0;i < NUM_STRINGS; i++)
    {
        printf("Input:\n");
        if (fgets(input[i], MAX, stdin) == NULL)
        {
            printf("EOF\n");
            break;
        }
        //remove newline
        input[i][strcspn(input[i], "\n")] = 0;
        printf("%s", input[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note, although you can use `ctrl-d`, you do not need to.  The loop will exit when `num_strings` is reached.